# You can not go without taking permission

Tags: active-voice

I am confused by this sentence:

> *You can not go without taking permission.*

How can I convert it into the passive voice? I tried this:

> *You can not go without permission being taken.*

But I'm not sure that's right.

Comment: First, the verb which collocates with *permission* is *get*, not *take* (one can not unilaterally *take* permission: by definition, it *must* be granted by the other party). Second you might want to say "*Permission must be gotten before leaving*" (though in this structure, we'd more likely use *granted* than *gotten*).

Comment: Sir,  How to change this sentence into passive voice?

Comment: Brother, I just showed you!

Comment: "without permission being acquired/attained" would work too I think but granted is better

Comment: The idiomatic expression would be ***receiving** permission*. In some foreign languages, the term for *receive* can be translated into English as *receive* or *take*. In my opinion, the expression *receiving permission* is adequately passive.

Comment: What about this? He can not go without having permission.

Comment: That would work, 124234.

Comment: To be technically in the passive voice, though, you would need: *He cannot go without being ________ permission.* You can fill in the blank with a word that makes sense like: *given, granted, accorded, assigned, awarded,  provided*, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it completely passive, I'd say "You cannot be going without permission being taken."

Three odd things, though: most people would say "get", not "take" permission. Also, "can not" from a native English speaker would look like a slightly oblique attempt to say "it's possible to avoid doing x". I'd go with "cannot" or "can't". And turning "go" passive is just so ugly, I can't imagine anywhere that it'd be better than active voice.

Comment: Sir , Gone or going?

Comment: "Be gone" by itself is more of a command; you could use it in place of "go" if you were telling someone to leave. To say "you cannot be gone" means "you cannot be absent". "You cannot be going" would seem to refer to a habitual action ("you can't be going to the casino every day") or to the actual progression of the journey ("if you will be going down this road, remember to watch for deer")